# How to get data from Android phone?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Lets say I want to get all my contacts list from my phone via bluetooth and 
list them on my pc.. is there any way to do it or some tutorials?

is it right that it needs that the phone in this case will be the "SERVER" 
so, in the phone i'll add an application that receives all the requests from my computer
and after that sends the results?

for example, lets say i want to enter the gallery in my phone from the pc. if i press
the button, it sends the phone a request, the application in the phone analyze the request, 
and then send to the pc via bluetooth all the files. so the phone needs to be the server like 
if if i have a website and server for the website.
is it correct?

Comment: Yes, yes and no. Only the phone needs to be server. PC application queries the phone server and gets the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  can use [android.bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). [This](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-quick-look-bluetoothadapter/) can give you a place to start.